# Let the eigen values of $A$ be distinct, $A=P\Lambda P^{-1}$ and $A^{T}=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$,show that $Q^{T}P=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Let the eigen values of $A$ be distinct, $A=P\Lambda P^{-1}$ and $A^{T}=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$,show that $PQ^{T}=I$ where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix.

We know that $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigen values, but how to show this?

Comment: I have made some progress that suppose $P^{-1}AP=Q^{-1}A^T Q=\Lambda \implies (PQ^T)A(PQ^T)^{-1}=A$

Comment: Can there be eigenvalue with multiplicity?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't true. Suppose it is true. Let $D\ne I$ be an arbitrary nonsingular diagonal matrix and $P_1=PD$. Then $A=P_1\Lambda P_1^{-1}$, but $Q^TP_1=Q^TPD=D\ne I$.

The conditions $A=P\Lambda P^{-1}$ and $A^T=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$ together imply that $Q^TP\Lambda=\Lambda Q^TP$. Since the only matrices that commute with a diagonal matrix with distinct diagonal entries are diagonal matrices, all you can say is that $Q^TP$ is a diagonal matrix. You cannot infer that $Q^TP=I$ without imposing further conditions.

Comment: Is it the same thing to show that $<p_i,q_j>=0 $ for all $i \neq j$ where $p_i,q_j$ are the $i$ th and $j$ th columns of $P$ and $Q$ respectively? Will this hold?

Comment: @LegendKiller If the vector space is Euclidean, yes. But I don't see any info about the underlying field here in this question.

Comment: okay i see that